# Help solving the following inequality

Tags: inequality

$$
\frac{x|x + 1|(x + 2)}{|x - 1|} \ge 0
$$

My idea was to multiply the denominator to $0$ and $| x + 1 |$ to solve it  in two cases  (when is positive and when is negative). No luck

Comment: Except for $x=-1$ it does not hold for $x \in (-2,0)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**

$$\frac{x|x + 1|(x + 2)}{|x - 1|} =\underbrace{\frac{|x + 1|}{|x - 1|}}_+.\left(x^2+2x\right)$$

Comment: It is $x^2 + 2x$

Comment: $(x^2 + 2x)$ instead of $(x^2+x)$.

Answer (score 0):

There are ***nine*** cases to check out, to cover all possible significant values of x; four are easy,

The LHS is zero  for $x=-2, -1, \text{and } 0$;  the inequality is **true**

The LHS is **undefined** for $x=1$;  the inequality is **false**

Now for the remaining five cases:in all of them the absolute value terms are positive, and can be ignored as to their effect on the sign of the LHS.  Only the $x$ and $x+2$ terms are **relevant**.

$x<-2$:  Both relevant terms are negative;  the product is positive and the inequality is **true**.

$-2 < x<-1$:  The two relevant terms differ in sign; the product is negative and the inequality is **false**.

$-1 < x<0$:  The two relevant terms differ in sign; the product is negative and the inequality is **false**.

$0 < x<1$:  The two relevant terms are positive; the product is positive and the inequality is **true**.

$x>1$:  The two relevant terms are positive; the product is positive and the inequality is **true**